# Check if image is empty for reused cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

**Each cell has an image.
I want to be able to check if the image is empty.**

I am using tableView's *reuseIdentifier*.

I have tried to do the following

```
if (!cell.imageView.image) {

}
```

and

```
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(cell.imageView.image.size, CGSizeZero)) {

}
```

But none of these approaches work, as the cell thinks the image exists, because previous cell's images exist (due to reused cells)

How do I get around this problem? **How do I check if a cell's image is empty or not in a reused cell?**

Comment: Why do you care? Simply nil it if you want to get rid of it, or if not then overwrite (or set it) to the value you want.

Comment: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to set the image as nil first for the appropriate condition (for example in _else_ block), so that the image is not reused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically if the cell is reused, the image won't be nil (unless you didn't set it). So  if you want to **not** reuse the images from your cells you can use `-prepareForReuse` method from UITableViewCell, this method is called right before the cell is reused, so in this method  you can make the image nil.

Comment: what you said is valid when few images are handled. If you are handling thousands of images and set image to nil every time, the performance will be quite shit if you are scrolling the tableview with high speed...

Comment: @Paradise my answer is related to the SO question, not related to the performance of a table view with thousands of images ;) .